# shadow in the picture

Tags: graphics, shadows

I try to put a drop shadow on a picture, so that it looks like it is sunk in the background. I only find ways to make a drop shadow on the background, so that it looks like the picture is on top of it.

In the link you can see, how I would like to have it:
https://data.starmind.com/question/f20587/14df8846f6e325179c546779d4571746.jpg

And here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols} 

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{\large{Test}} 

\begin{columns} 
 \column[]{2in}
  \begin{block}{Block over background}
   \begin{itemize}
        \item  Item 1
        \item  Item 2
        \item  Item 3
        \item  Item 4
   \end{itemize}
  \end{block}       

 \column[]{2in}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rounded corners=2pt,drop shadow={shadow xshift=.8ex,shadow yshift=-.8ex},fill=blue,draw]at (0,0) {\rule{2cm}{2cm}};
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{Picture over background}
    \end{figure} 
\end{columns}}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Look at the TikZ `shadows` library.

Comment: Hei ! thanks for the tip. I checked the TikZ shadows library and found a way to make the shadow on the background (tikzpicture->node->drop shadow), but I can't find a command to but the shadow on the picture itself.

Comment: You can change the options for the shadow or use the generic shadow rather than `drop shadow` if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your help cfr, unfortunately I couldn't find it out. The options for the shadow to shift, scale and the node options to fill  the picture doesn't give me the right results. I couldn't find anything about the generic shadow. I use this pdf about the shadows options:ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-blur/pgf-blur.pdf